# Firestore Function Console.log

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

What am I missing? Trying to use console.log() to debug a Firestore function. The firestore function logs show the error details, however I cannot seem to get console.log() to add debugging message to the Log:

Here is the function Log error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
      at exports.updateIndex.functions.firestore.document.onCreate.event (/srv/index.js:13:36)
      at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
      at /worker/worker.js:825:24
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Here is the function code in index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateIndex = functions.firestore
.document('Documents/{Name}')
.onCreate(event => {

   const documentId = event.params.document.id;
    const id = this.document ? this.document.id : '';
    console.log("Update Index for Doc", document);

    const document = event.after.data();

    console.log("docId",documentId,"id",id);

    const searchableIndex = newFunction(document)

    const indexedDocument = { ...document, searchableIndex }

    const db = admin.firestore()

    return db.collection('Documents').doc(document.id).set(indexedDocument, { merge: true })

})

function newFunction(document) {
    return createIndex(document.Name);
}

function createIndex(document) {
    const arr = Name.toLowerCase().split('');
    const searchableIndex = {}
console.log("Creating Index");
    let prevKey = '';

    for (const char of arr) {
        const key = prevKey + char;
        searchableIndex[key] = true
        prevKey = key
    }
    console.log("Create docId",documentId,"id",id);
    return searchableIndex
}
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I don't see how the error is related to the code you're showing.  There isn't a property called `document` anywhere in that code.

Comment: Doug, you are correct, I have included the complete function. My question is how to get the console.log() messages to show up in the firestore Logs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting into the `console.log` cause your code is breaking at this line:

```
const id = this.document ? this.document.id : '';
```

since it cannot find `this`, it will try to set `this.document.id` and crash.

so to your specific question, `console.log` works as you think it does, just make sure you code reach that log first, you can move the log before the error line and you should get it

```
exports.updateIndex = functions.firestore
.document('Documents/{Name}')
.onCreate(event => {

   const documentId = event.params.document.id;

    /*********
     HERE IT WILL WORK
    ********/
    console.log(documentId) // Cool!

    const id = this.document ? this.document.id : ''; // ERROR LINE
    console.log("Update Index for Doc", document);

    const document = event.after.data();

    console.log("docId",documentId,"id",id); // WONT WORK

    const searchableIndex = newFunction(document)

    const indexedDocument = { ...document, searchableIndex }

    const db = admin.firestore()

    return db.collection('Documents').doc(document.id).set(indexedDocument, { merge: true })

})
```

The other thing you need to figure out is what does `this` refers to?  I think you have an error of concepts there

Comment: Yes,  I have not used this before so now I know how to do it. Thank you!